# I need List Plot points to have different color based on amount of neighbours?

Tags: plotting

So i have a list of points, and i need them to be colored differently based on how many neighbours they have.
I tried:

```
ListPlot[Nearest[list, list, {Infinity, 2}], 
ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

but this doesnt work.
 Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Update: The List im using is About 6000 numbers long.
Here is a part of it:

```
{{14.24, 12.5}, {14.15, 12.67}, {14.22, 12.36}, {14.17, 12.71}, 
{13.61, 12.42}, {14.35, 12.49}, {14.12, 12.68}, {14.26, 12.59}, 
{14.07, 12.56}, {14.19, 12.57}, {14.06, 12.9}, {14.17, 12.59}, 
{14.19, 12.67}, {14.23, 12.5}, {14.07, 12.49}, {14.45, 12.45}, {13.7, 
12.8}, {14.12, 12.59}, {14.07, 12.7}, {14.23, 13.07}, {13.83, 12.13}, 
{14.35, 12.79}, {13.92, 12.41}, {14.08, 12.65}, {13.68, 12.16}, 
{13.84, 13.18}, {13.58, 11.61}, {12.58, 12.3}, {12.84, 13.25}, 
{13.57, 12.66}, {13.74, 12.18}, {13.24, 12.33}, {13.05, 12.47}, 
{13.26, 12.67}, {13.7, 12.35}, {13.68, 10.79}, {13.35, 12.19}, 
{13.77, 12.46}, {13.67, 12.15}, {12.75, 12.21}, {13.06, 12.81}}
```

Comment: To make it easy for us to help you it's always a good idea to post a (reasonable) data set representative of your own.  As it stands, you depend on the kindness of strangers to make a guess at a suitable `lst` for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nc = Length /@ Nearest[list, list, {Infinity, 2}];
minmax = MinMax[nc];
legend = SwatchLegend[ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}] /@ Union[nc], 
   Union@nc, LegendLabel -> "Neighbor Counts", 
   LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"];
```

#### ListPlot

You can wrap each data point with `List` and use the option `PlotStyle` to style each point differently:

```
ListPlot[List /@ list, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[PointSize[Large], ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}]@#] & /@ nc), 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Top], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can style each data point differently by wrapping it with `Style` as in Jon's answer:

```
ListPlot[Style[#, ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}][#2]] & @@@ Transpose[{list, nc}],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Top], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

#### BubbleChart

You can also use [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) by appending to each data point its neighbor count:

```
BubbleChart[Join[list, List /@ nc,  2], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 BubbleSizes -> {.02, .02}, ChartLegends -> Placed[legend, Top]]
```

[image]

#### RelationGraph

```
rg = RelationGraph[EuclideanDistance[##] <= 2 &, list];
cols = ColorData[{"Rainbow", MinMax@#}] /@ # &[1 + DegreeCentrality[rg]];
Legended[Graph[rg, 
  VertexSize -> {Divide @@ (Subtract @@@ CoordinateBounds[list]), 1}/30, 
  VertexCoordinates -> list, 
  EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[rg] -> cols], Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> All, AspectRatio -> 1], Placed[legend, Top]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work - choose your own styling function...

```
nearCount[pt_, list_, dist_] := Length[Nearest[list, pt, {Infinity, dist}]];
styleByCount[pt_] := Style[pt, GrayLevel[nearCount[pt, list, 0.2]/15]];
ListPlot[styleByCount /@ list]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your data = `dat` define a measure function between points. This is arbitrary.

```
measure[p1_, p2_] := 1/(.1 + Norm[p1 - p2]);
```

Assume a point's total measure is the sum of the measures between points. Get the total measures of points.

```
outerRes = Total@Outer[measure[#1, #2] &, dat, dat, 1]
```

Extend our data to 3D

```
augdat = Transpose@Join[Transpose[dat], {outerRes}];
```

Look at 3D plot (fun)...

```
ListPointPlot3D[augdat, 
          ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
          ]
```

[image]

Looking down from directly overhead by setting Viewpoint to get 2D view.

```
ListPointPlot3D[augdat,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]],
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]