# How to improve the rendering time of a plot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

The following is a link my original question:

[I need List Plot points to have different color based on amount of neighbours?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191012/i-need-list-plot-points-to-have-different-color-based-on-amount-of-neighbours)

The question was answered, and I used the first answer with `ListPlot`.
It worked very well, taking maybe 10 seconds with 6k numbers in the list.

Now I have expanded the list of points to 120k and it wont work, not even when I let it run for a really long time. The rroblem is with the expression

```
List /@ list
```

I think that `ListPlot` can't handle a list containing 120k sublists, but maybe I'm wrong. I tried all the other answers given to my previous question, but they don't really work either even though I have 50 GB pf working memory.

Any ideas would be great.

Here's what a small sample of my list looks like.

```
{{14.24, 12.5}, {14.15, 12.67}, {14.22, 12.36}, {14.17, 12.71}, 
{13.61, 12.42}, {14.35, 12.49}, {14.12, 12.68}, {14.26, 12.59}, 
{14.07, 12.56}, {14.19, 12.57}, {14.06, 12.9}, {14.17, 12.59}, 
{14.19, 12.67}, {14.23, 12.5}, {14.07, 12.49}, {14.45, 12.45}, {13.7, 
12.8}, {14.12, 12.59}, {14.07, 12.7}, {14.23, 13.07}, {13.83, 12.13}, 
{14.35, 12.79}, {13.92, 12.41}, {14.08, 12.65}, {13.68, 12.16}, 
{13.84, 13.18}, {13.58, 11.61}, {12.58, 12.3}, {12.84, 13.25}, 
{13.57, 12.66}, {13.74, 12.18}, {13.24, 12.33}, {13.05, 12.47}, 
{13.26, 12.67}, {13.7, 12.35}, {13.68, 10.79}, {13.35, 12.19}, 
{13.77, 12.46}, {13.67, 12.15}, {12.75, 12.21}, {13.06, 12.81}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work quite well for the visualization and returns results after a few seconds; in particular if we follow Carl Woll's suggestion and use the `VertexColor` option of the `Point` primitive.

```
n = 120000;
r = 0.1;
list = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[2]], n];
nc = Length /@ Nearest[list -> Automatic, list, {Infinity, r}];

Graphics[
 Point[list, VertexColors -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[N[nc]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Notice that the value of `r` is crucial for the runtime of `Nearest` (its runtime increases rapidly with `r`). But the runtime of `Graphics` should be independent of that.

Comment: It is much faster to use a multipoint object with VertexColors, e.g., `Graphics[Point[list, 
  VertexColors -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[N[nc]]]]`

Comment: Ha! Great! I did not know how to do that (I tried  `GraphicsComplex`).